# Problems with list populating

Tags: c#

This has happened to me more than once and I can't figure out what it could be. I have a list of crafting recipes which I add like so:

```
        ItemRecipe firePitRecipe = new ItemRecipe();
        firePitRecipe.Items.Add(new Rock());
        foreach (Item item in firePitRecipe.Items)
        {
            item.ItemCount = 5;
        }
        firePitRecipe.Output = new FirePit();
        firePitRecipe.Name = "firepit";
        CraftingList.Add(firePitRecipe);
```

I currently have 6 recipes in the list. When I try to craft an item, nothing shows up in the box that shows my crafts available. When I comment out the line and the last two recipes:

```
//firePitRecipe.Items.Add(new Rock());
```

Everything works as it should. I have no idea what this bug could be. Is it because I'm creating a new instance of an item every time I add to recipe.Items?

```
      public class Rock : Item
{
    Texture2D texture;

    public Rock()
    {
        this.Texture = texture;
        ItemName = "rock";
        ItemType itemType = ItemType.craft;
    }

    public Rock(Vector2 position)
    {
        texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("rock");

        this.Position = position;
        this.Texture = texture;

        ItemName = "rock";
        ItemType itemType = ItemType.craft;
        ItemPickedUp = false;
    }
}
```

This is my rock class and all of my other items are similar. There is nothing odd about it so I dont see anything wrong. Setting a breakpoint reveals that none of the items in my crafting list are null.

The other thing it may be is when I loop through the list and check them against my items in my inventory, but I doubt thats it.

I narrowed it down to a couple of methods. They are just not being drawn or set correctly in the table.

```
 private void SetItemPositionInTable(Player player, Item output)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CraftingTableItems.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (CraftingTableItems[i].ItemName == "empty")
            {
                CraftingTableItems[i].ItemName = output.ItemName;
                CraftingTableItems[i].Texture = output.Texture;
                Console.WriteLine(output.ItemName);
                break;
            }
            else if (CraftingTableItems[i].ItemName == output.ItemName)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (CraftingTableItems[i].ItemName != "empty" && output.ItemName == "empty")
            {
                CraftingTableItems[i].ItemName = "empty";
            }
        }
    }

  public void DrawCraftingTable(SpriteBatch sb, Player player, SpriteFont font)
    {
        if (player.DrawCraftingTable == true)
        {
            sb.Draw(Texture, CraftingRectangle, Color.White);

            foreach (Item item in CraftingTableItems)
            {
                if (item.ItemName != "empty")
                {
                    sb.Draw(item.Texture, item.ItemSlotPosition, Color.White);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm confused because this works with 3 items in the list but not 6? Here is the crafting table list.

```
              CraftingTableItems = new List<Item>(12);

        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                CraftingTableItems.Add(new Item(new Vector2((int)(64 * x), (int)(64 * y)), "empty"));
            }
        }
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to debug. Please provide a codebase that produces the bug.

Comment: I have no idea what is producing the bug. Its just that one line that after removal, makes the objects in my crafting box draw again. I was wondering if there were some limitations on adding items to a list that I don't know about

Comment: What is the purpose of this code: `foreach (Item item in firePitRecipe.Items)
        {
            item.ItemCount = 5;
        }
`?

Comment: Its the amount of items needed to craft the fire pit. I would need 5 rocks. I dont know why I put that into a loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have given us enough code to know what goes wrong. This is something that caught my eye:

```
public class Rock : Item
{
    Texture2D texture;  // This isn't initialized so it is null?

    public Rock()
    {
        this.Texture = texture;  // Here the assumed null is assigned to base class Texture
        ItemName = "rock";
        ItemType itemType = ItemType.craft;
    }
    ...
```

Because you are creating a rock with `new Rock()`, `this.Texture` will remain null based on what you have shown us. When drawing that rock later, perhaps if fails because of that missing texture.

Comment: I found out that my SetItemPosition method isn't working correctly. In the console whenever a craft is available it writes a line. But my crafting table is still empty. I just can't find the error in the SetItemPositionInTable method.

Comment: Well, if you set one "empty" item in your crafting table, it seems to clear the whole table, ie. it sets "empty" to all crafting table slots. I don't know if this is desired behaviour or not though...

Comment: Good job catching that. That wasn't my intention but it fixed my problem!